# If Else Script With Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a current set of inserts into an IF Else script.  To add more,

IF SELECT query is null then do another query (Insert query into another table).  I want to trigger an insert into a different if a column is null from another different table.

If column x from table z is null 
Then 
Insert into table y
(Select column a from from table q)
Else do nothing
End

What do I have to do from this point on?  There are two tables, whereby if one column is not set, that will trigger an insert into another table.

Let me know if I need to further clarify.  If this isn't an If Else type of script, which route can I follow?

```
            BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT X FROM #temp WHERE X IS NULL) THEN
            insert into a
            select * from b
            END IF;
            END
```

Comment: What is `is not set`? `NULL`?

Comment: Correct.  Or could be < 1.

Comment: Yes, you need to further clarify.

Comment: This is not clear.  VTC

Comment: There must be a key that ties the three tables together (the join conditions).

Comment: This is now your 4th question like this and none are clear.  You need to improve your questions.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do `IF NOT EXISTS (<<Query to check some conditions>>) INSERT INTO y ...`

Comment: @Bridge that is what I want to do.

Comment: You have 278 points so you are not a beginner. Please provide the additional details (like the columns used to match up the tables) and whatever other information requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's the question here, but you have a syntax error in the code you provided in the question (maybe that's the problem?)
Here is how it should be written:

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT X FROM #temp WHERE X IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        insert into a
        select * from b
    END
END
```

Please note that since your `IF` only have one statement after it, you could write it without the `begin...end`, however IMHO that's less readable:

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT X FROM #temp WHERE X IS NULL) 
        insert into a
        select * from b
END
```